# How do I fetch association data from a list of users through a many to many relationship in doctrine query builder

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

I can't figure out how to do this using the query builder in Doctrine:

On a high level, I wan to fetch all of the userTags which are associated to each user, and I am fetching each user from user relationship table by their parent id.

Something like this:
`from UserRelationship -> get users by parent_id -> also get each user's associated userTags`. It's the last bit that I can't get the `userTags`. Idealy I would select only the `id` and `name` params from that table, as the rest, like company and users is redundant.

I have this query builder query in Symfony 3.* Doctrine 2.*

#### UserRelationshipRepository.php

```
protected function getBaseSubordinateQuery($managerId ){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

    $qb
        ->select(
            'u.id',
            'u.username',
            'u.email',
            'u.first_name',
            'u.last_name',
            'u.lastLogin',
            'u.userTags', // <-- How do I get these values?
            'c.phone',
            'c.position as jobTitle',
            'co.name as company',
            'c.createdAt',
            'max(cl.expiresAt) as expiresAt',
            'cl.expiresAt',
            'c.yearsInPosition as titleSince',
            'c.skype',
            'c.linkedin',
            'c.yearsAtCompany',
            'up.path as imgPath',
            'up.name as imgName',
            'up.format as imgFormat'
        )
        ->innerJoin( 'r.child', 'u' )
        ->innerJoin( 'u.clientInfo', 'c' )
        ->leftJoin( 'u.userTags', 'ut' )
        ->where('ut IS NOT NULL')
        ->leftJoin( 'u.company', 'co' )
        ->leftJoin( 'c.clientLicense', 'cl' )
        ->leftJoin( 'u.userPhotos', 'up' )
        ->where ( $qb->expr()->eq('r.parent', ':manager') )
        ->setParameter('manager', $managerId)
    ;

    return $qb;
```

Note: as it is, that query gives me an error: `500 Internal Server Error. [Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'userTags, c.phone,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

#### User.php

```
    /**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|\Reddin\Bundle\CMSBundle\Entity\UserTag[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Reddin\Bundle\CMSBundle\Entity\UserTag", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_user_tags")
 *
 * @JMS\Groups({"tags"})
 * @JMS\MaxDepth(2)
 */
protected $userTags;
```

#### UserTag.php

```
class UserTag
{
    use Timestampable;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Many UserTags belong to one Company.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reddin\Bundle\CMSBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="userTags", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(2)
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|\Reddin\Bundle\UserAccountBundle\Entity\User[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Reddin\Bundle\UserAccountBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="userTags", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @JMS\MaxDepth(2)
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * Company constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "" . $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return UserTag
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @return UserTag
     */
    public function getCompany() {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * @param Company $company
     * @return UserTag
     */
    public function setCompany(Company $company = null) {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
'u.userTags',
```

with

```
'ut'
```

This will solve the error you are getting, but probably you will get others.
I suggest change the query to:

```
$qb
    ->select(
        'r',
        'u',
        'ut',
        ...
```

Also replace the 2nd where to:
    ->andWhere ( $qb->expr()->eq('r.parent', ':manager') )

Then you can fetch the tags for each user:

```
 $userRel->getChild()->getUserTags();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid doing another query to get the tags, and avoid loading entire objects. In the end I switched to native SQL querying and it was easier and more intuitive to rationalize about it. I'll Accept this answer for whoever might find it useful.